# If the product of two integers is odd, then both are odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Prove $ \forall x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ if $x\times y$ is odd then $x$ and $y$ are odd.

Is this valid proof? 
Proof by contrapositive. The contrapositive of the implication is: $ \forall x, y \in \mathbb{Z} $if $x$ and $y$ are not both odd then $x \times y$ is even.

To prove the contrapositive of the implication, let $x = 2k$ for some arbitrary $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. We cannot assume anything about $y$ to keep generality. Then $x \times y =  2k \times y = 2ky = 2(ky)$. Because $x \times y$ is a multiple of $2$ the implication holds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a good idea, but that's not quite the contrapositive. The contrapositive would be: "If $x$ and $y$ (integers) are not both odd, then $xy$ is also not odd." Another way of phrasing this would be "Let $x,y\in\Bbb{Z}$. If $x$ *or* $y$ is even, then $xy$ is even." I think you can finish it from here!

Comment: Thank you! Pesky De Morgan's Law!

Answer (score 3):

No, the contrapositive is "if $x$ **or** $y$ is even then $xy$ is even". It's very easy to modify your proof. Assume that $x$ is even, but don't assume that $y$ is even.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that a direct proof is preferable in this case. What is the general form of an odd integer? Once you’ve written your two factors in this form, it’s plain that their product is odd.

Comment: I started out doing a direct proof but I thought that setting $x = 2m + 1$ and $y = 2n + 1$ then doing $(2m + 1)(2n+1)$ just proves the converse of the implication. Am I incorrect in assuming this?

Comment: Yes, you're doing the converse there.  (P) implies (Q) has the converse (Q) implies (P).  So if your statement is that (P)=(xy odd) implies (Q)=(x,y odd), the converse would be (Q)=(x,y odd) implies (P)=(xy odd).

By starting with the assumption (x,y odd), you're starting with the conclusion you're trying to draw.